# Why is the variable that's being passed to the child component not being updated?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am passing the expandedItem variable to a child component and when the app state changes it needs to update this variable value and re-send it to the child component.  Currently, the value is updated in the parent when the app state is changed but its not getting re-sent to the child component thus it still has the default value.  Does anyone know how to get the value to be re-sent to the child component?

Here is my cart item view (child component).  The isExpanded variable needs to get updated from the app state change in order to control which views should be expanded and collapsed.

```
render() {
    const isExpanded = this.props.expandedViewId === product.id;
```

The render line of the parent component:

```
render() {
     const {isLoading, displayDetails, sortCasesAsc, details, items, expandedItem} = this.props.orderInfo;
```

**Here is where the expandedItem variable gets passed to the child component:**

```
    <FlatList 
            data={items}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id.toString()}
            renderItem={({item}) => <CartProductItem product={item} expandedViewId={expandedItem} onExpandClick={(id) => this.expandAndCollapseItems(id)} />}
        />
```

Function that triggers the variable update:

```
expandAndCollapseItems = (id) => {
    this.props.dispatch(collapseCartItemViews(id));
}
```

The cart action function:

```
export function collapseCartItemViews(id) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch({
            type: types.SET_EXPANDED_STATE,
            id: id
        });
    }
}
```

The reducer function:

```
    case types.SET_EXPANDED_STATE:
        const id = action.id;

        return {
            ...state,
            expandedItem: id
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here:

`const isExpanded = this.props.expandedViewId = product.id;`

should be

`const isExpanded = this.props.expandedViewId === product.id;`

Comment: I actually meant to fix that just forget... but no that does not make a difference to the expandedViewId getting updated or re-sent in.  It's not even re-evaluating it in the child component after an app state change.  The expandedViewId is set in the parent component.